# Why cant i pass props to another page? Cannot read proprty of undefined comes up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'd like to pass the value of localUserId to another screen ( defined in Table.js)

In my **App.js** i have:

```
goToTable() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Table', { userIdForPrivacyToggle: this.state.localUserId } )
  }


  render() {

      return (
            <View style={styles.TableButton}>
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.goToTable()}>  
                        <Icon style={styles.icon} name="list" size={25} color="#FF7400" resizeMode='contain' />   
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                   </View>

)}
```

In my **Table.js**

```
export default class TableClass extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {

          userIdForPrivacyToggle: this.props.navigation.state.params.userIdForPrivacyToggle,

        };

       Foo() {
            Alert.alert(this.state.userIdForPrivacyToggle)
       }

render() {

      return (
            <View style={styles.container}> 
                      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={this.Foo}>  
                        <Icon style={styles.icon} name="icon" size={30} color="#FF7400" resizeMode='contain' />   
                      </TouchableOpacity>
          </View> 

)}

    }
```

When i click the button to call Foo() i get the error:

```
cannot read property 'userIdForPrivacyToggle' of undefined
```

Is there something wrong with the onPress methods? What could be going wrong

Comment: read console.log(this.props) above this.state=...  inside constructor of table.js and you should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Foo() needed to be onPress={()=>this.Foo()}

Comment: or use an arrow function: `Foo = () => {....}` or binding the method in the constructor `this.Foo = this.Foo.bind(this)`. Whatever you prefer, as long as you preserve `this` when passing `onPress={this.Foo}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `<TouchableOpacity />` but usually invoking methods straight away is a bad idea. I guess what you want to do is to pass the method down in order to invoke it where you need it to.

Try this in App.js:
`<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.goToTable}>`